# Support function of Minkowski Difference

Tags: collision-detection

I am watching [this](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1017646/Physics-for-Game-Programmers-The) and if you stop at 7:25, you will find an implementation of the support function. The goal of the function is to give you the farthest point in a given direction. My question is how do we achieve this without looking at all the points in the Minkowski Difference? How is this not an O(m*n) algorithm ? Is there a way to get just the points that lie on the edges (I am asking because in the slide after that he just shows the edge points and not all the internal ones)? Am I missing something ?